# How to generate all possible strings in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

My goal is to be able to generate all possible strings (Letters and numbers) of length x and be able to activate a block of code for each one. (like an iterator) The only problem is the ones in the itertools don't make copies of the letter in the same string. For example:

I get "ABC"  "BAC" "CAB" etc. instead of "AAA".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> map(''.join, itertools.product('ABC', repeat=3))
['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BBA', 'BBB', 'BBC', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CBA', 'CBB', 'CBC', 'CCA', 'CCB', 'CCC']
```

Note that creating a list containing all combinations is very inefficient for longer strings - iterate over them instead:

```
for string in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.product('ABC', repeat=3)):
    print string
```

To get all characters and numbers use `string.uppercase + string.lowercase + string.digits`.

Comment: Python 3 changed so that the builtin `map` now returns an iterator.  The second suggestion of using `itertools.imap` is not necessary unless you're version of python is < 3.0.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) if you want letters to repeat:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> for combo in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=3):
...     print ''.join(combo)
...
AAA
AAB
...
ZZY
ZZZ
```

`itertools.combinations()` and `itertools.permutations()` are not the correct tools for your job.