# Given a list of strings, print all combinations of strings choosing 1 character from each

Tags: algorithm, combinations, computer-science

I am trying to find the most efficient way to solve this problem. Currently, I have a solution in which I create a mapping of strings to their string lengths and then use a helper function to stitch together the characters and decrement the mapping list as I go. When the current value decrements to a 0, the number to its left decrements by 1 and then that number + numbers to its right reset to their length-1. The implementation for that looks like this:

```
def printCombinations(s):
    data_lens = []
    s = [x for x in s if x]
    for idx,val in enumerate(s): #create string length mapping list
        if len(val) == 0:
            s = s[0:idx]+s[idx+1:] #remove empty strings
            idx = idx -1
        else:
            data_lens.append(len(s[idx])-1)
    total_combos = 1
    for i in data_lens:
        total_combos = total_combos * (i+1) #total combos = lengths of the strings multiplied by each other
    current_index = len(s)-1

    while total_combos > 0:
        data_lens_copy = data_lens[:]
        if data_lens[current_index] >= 0: #if current number >= 0
            print(generateString(data_lens_copy, s))
            data_lens[current_index] -= 1
            total_combos -=1
        else:
            if current_index > 0:
                while data_lens[current_index] <= 0: #shift left while <= 0
                    current_index -= 1

                if data_lens[current_index] >= 0:
                    data_lens[current_index] -= 1
                    for i in range(current_index+1,len(s)):
                        data_lens[i] = len(s[i])-1
                    current_index = len(s)-1

def generateString(indices, strings):
    resultStr = ""
    for i in range(len(indices)-1,-1,-1):
        current_str = strings[i]
        current_index = indices[i]
        if current_str != "":
            resultStr = current_str[current_index] + resultStr
        indices[i] -= 1
    return resultStr
```

While this solution gets the job done, it creates a mapping list of equal size and iteratively resets the mapping values to the right whenever a number hits 0. What's a more efficient way to print out all combinations of strings in which 1 character comes from each string element?

`ex: ["dog","cat"] -> dc,da,dt,oc,oa,ot,gc,ga,gt`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347583/how-to-generate-all-possible-strings-in-python ?

Comment: Look at `itertools.product`

Comment: Clarification: I'm not looking for a library to accomplish this. Instead, I'm trying to understand how one could implement this type of algorithm themselves. The goal here is to understand the algorithmic technique behind this type of problem. Maybe remove the python tag? Thought I would add it there since my implementation was in Python

Comment: You have implemented counting from max value `total_combos` downto zero in mixed-radix numeral system (where radix for k-th digit is length of k-th string). This is quite effective way.  Also simple recursive way does exist (good for not very long items). IMHO, it would better to remove Python tag

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `itertools.product` and are looking to understand the algorithm, one way is to define a recursive algorithm.  It's faster than the original code (about 16x), but comparisons with `print` involved are iffy.

```
def product(item,*args):
    # termination condition: if only one string, yield the characters.
    if not args:
        yield from item
    else:
        # Recursion, yield the character for each item,
        # combined with the results of the remaining strings
        for c in item:
            for d in product(*args):
                yield c + d

print(list(product('dog','cat')))
print(list(product('ab','cd','def')))
```

Output:

```
['dc', 'da', 'dt', 'oc', 'oa', 'ot', 'gc', 'ga', 'gt']
['acd', 'ace', 'acf', 'add', 'ade', 'adf', 'bcd', 'bce', 'bcf', 'bdd', 'bde', 'bdf']
```

Comment: Good solution, but I was wondering if you can provide an alternative solution in which it prints results as it's executing and not after all of it was processed and the argument passed is an array rather than a dynamic number of arguments.

Comment: @btrballin Instead of `*args` use `args`, and pass `args[0],args[1:]` in the recursive call.  `for item in product('dog','cat'): print(item)` would print as it goes.  You can't really print in the function itself due to the recursion...it would print intermediate results.