# Function that generates all words out of n characters that can be A,B or C

Tags: python, recursion

We need to make a function that makes all combinations out of **A**, **B**, and **C** with lenght of ***n***. I tryed making something, I only made it work for 0, 1, and 2 but I dont know how to make it using recursion or nested loops.

Example for `n=3`:

AAA, BAA, CAA, ABA, BBA, CBA, ACA, BCA, CCA, AAB, BAB, CAB, ABB, BBB, CBB, ACB, BCB, CCB, AAC, BAC, CAC, ABC, BBC, CBC, ACC, BCC, CCC

---

```
def generator (n):

    complete = [ ]

    words = ["A", "B", "C",]

    if (n==1):
        for word1 in words:
            complete.append(word1)
        return complete

    elif (n==0):
        return complete

    else:
        for word1 in words:
            for word2 in words:
                complete.append(word1+word2)

    return complete



n = int(input("Lenght n: "))

complete = (generator(n))

print(', '.join(complete))
```

Comment: `list(itertools.product("abc", repeat=3))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate all possible strings in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347583/how-to-generate-all-possible-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is recursion logic, you need to change it somehow to presents recursion logic correctly, below is an example :

```
    ...
    #produce results for n-1 length so we can use it later
    res=generator(n-1)
    for word1 in words:
            # for each partial result (length n-1) we can generate final result by concatenating current word to it
            for r1 in res:
                complete.append(word1+r1)
```

Entire code:

```
def generator (n):

    complete = [ ]

    words = ["A", "B", "C",]

    if (n==1):
        for word1 in words:
            complete.append(word1)
        return complete

    elif (n==0):
        return complete

    else:
        res=generator(n-1)
        for word1 in words:
                for r1 in res:
                    complete.append(word1+r1)

    return complete
```

and the result for n=3 : (27 strings)

```
['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BBA', 'BBB', 'BBC', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CBA', 'CBB', 'CBC', 'CCA', 'CCB', 'CCC']
```

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the problem in java using Recursion:

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = String.valueOf(words);
  printCombinations(str);
}

private static void printCombinations(String str) {
  printPermutation(str, "");
}

private static void printPermutation(String str, String str2) {
  if (str2.length() == str.length()) {
    //   printing the combination
    System.out.println(str2);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    printPermutation(str, str2 + str.charAt(i));
  }
}
```