# kdb/q: generate all possible "strings" of length N

Tags: kdb

in KDB/Q, how do I generate all combinations given an alphabet universe (doesn't have to be string, could be like a list of numbers) for a given size n?

What I am looking for is similar to this in python, but in q.
[How to generate all possible strings in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347583/how-to-generate-all-possible-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `cross` would be the easiest method:

```
q){y(x cross)/x}["ABC";1]
"AA"
"AB"
"AC"
"BA"
"BB"
"BC"
"CA"
"CB"
"CC"

q){y(x cross)/x}["ABC";2]
"AAA"
"AAB"
"AAC"
...
```